# programmatically switching the task leads to strange behavior after calling the function

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, osdev

I write a kernel in C and assembler and work on multitasking, I wrote a function that switches tasks just by switching the stack, it works and the tasks switch correctly, but the function that I call after initializing the task behaves strangely.

I'll describe it in more detail:
Its logic is designed so that if the thread was not started earlier, it is started using call so that return works adequately, and if the code was previously started but control is passed using ret.

However, here's the problem: after calling the thread function, as soon as return is triggered there, the scheduler_thread_exit_current() function should be called, which terminates the thread and removes it from the queue. this function prints data about threads, but it does it [incorrectly](https://github.com/mrjbom/OS/blob/f6dccc909509f1255d0f0d24384adffbcbac97e8/serial.log#L35).
However, if you just call a function that prints data about threads, it does it [normally](https://github.com/mrjbom/OS/blob/f6dccc909509f1255d0f0d24384adffbcbac97e8/serial.log#L19).

It turns out that calling the print data function inside the thread completion function does not work correctly, but separately it works as it should.

I suppose it has something to do with the stack and possibly the ebp register, what's the problem?

Code which deals with task switching(snippet or click  [here](https://github.com/mrjbom/OS/blob/f6dccc909509f1255d0f0d24384adffbcbac97e8/source/scheduler/task_switch.S#L22))

```
    .section .bss

    //tmp 4 byte value
    tmp_var: .space 4, 0


    .section .text

    .extern current_thread
    .extern next_thread

    .extern saved_regs
    .extern scheduler_thread_exit_current

    .global scheduler_low_thread_switch


    //eax = current_thread
    //ebx = next_thread
    //ecx = pointers
    //edx = comparisons
    scheduler_low_thread_switch:
        push %EBP
        pushf
        mov saved_regs, %ECX
        //save general-purpose registers into stack
        push 4(%ECX)  //push EDI
        push 8(%ECX)  //push ESI
        push 20(%ECX) //push EBX
        push 24(%ECX) //push EDX
        push 32(%ECX) //push EAX
        mov 28(%ECX), %EAX //load saved ECX into EAX
        push %EAX //push ECX

        mov current_thread, %EAX
        mov next_thread, %EBX
        mov %ESP, 16(%EAX)  //save old task ESP
        mov 16(%EBX), %ESP  //load new task ESP


        jmp check_next_thread_kernel_or_userspace


    //is this thread owned by a kernel process?
    check_next_thread_kernel_or_userspace:
        mov 0(%EBX), %ECX //loading address with process info
        mov 272(%ECX), %DH //loading kernel flag
        mov $1, %DL      //if 1 - kernel thread, if 0 - userspace thread
        cmp %DH, %DL
        je kernel_check_next_thread_init_or_continue
        jne userspace_check_next_thread_init_or_continue


    kernel_check_next_thread_init_or_continue:
        mov 32(%EBX), %DH //loading is_inited flag
        mov $0, %DL //if 1 - need continue, if 0 - need init
        cmp %DH, %DL
        je kernel_next_thread_init
        jne kernel_next_thread_continue

    kernel_next_thread_init:
        mov 20(%EBX), %ECX //save entry_point
        mov %ECX, tmp_var
        //load saved general-purpose registers from stack
        pop %ECX
        pop %EAX
        pop %EDX
        pop %EBX
        pop %ESI
        pop %EDI
        popf
        pop %EBP
        call *tmp_var
        call scheduler_thread_show_list //test c func call
        call scheduler_thread_show_list //test c func call
        call scheduler_thread_show_list //test c func call
        call scheduler_thread_exit_current


    kernel_next_thread_continue:
        pop %ECX
        pop %EAX
        pop %EDX
        pop %EBX
        pop %ESI
        pop %EDI
        popf
        pop %EBP
        ret

    userspace_check_next_thread_init_or_continue:
```

scheduler_thread_exit_current()

```
    void scheduler_thread_exit_current() {
        /* Отключаем прерывания */
        __asm__ volatile ("cli");

        serial_printf("END THREAD LIST\n");
        scheduler_thread_show_list();

        //serial_printf("scheduler_thread_exit_current\n"
        //              "current_thread id = %u\n", current_thread->id);

        /* Удаляем поток из очереди */
        thread_list = g_list_remove(thread_list, current_thread);
        /* Уменьшаем число потоков в процессе, которому он принадлежит */
        current_thread->process->threads_count--;

        /* Освобождаем память, занятую потоком под стек и собственный описатель */
        pm_free(current_thread->stack);
        pm_free(current_thread);

        /* Грузим в ECX адрес планировщика */
        __asm__ volatile ("mov %0, %%ecx"::"a"(&scheduler_switch));

        /* Включаем прерывания */
        __asm__ volatile ("sti");

        /* Вызываем планировщик */
        __asm__ volatile ("call *%ecx");
    }
```

Comment: to switch tasks you need to switch more than stacks, flags, and registers at a minimum, you are doing all of that?  (I see no code in the question).

Comment: @old_timer, how can you not see it? See the first snippet at the end of the question. Here's a [link](https://github.com/mrjbom/OS/blob/f6dccc909509f1255d0f0d24384adffbcbac97e8/source/scheduler/task_switch.S#L22) just in case

Comment: I dont follow links, you need to post the minimal example to demonstrate the problem in the question...see @ryyker's comment above.

Comment: @old_timer, try clicking this button "Show code snippet" in the question

Comment: @ryyker That's not a link, that's a feature of Stack Overflow to hide overly long code snippets.

Comment: @ryyker, I made it easier, now the code is displayed immediately and you don't need to click any buttons.

Clicking on the "Show code snippet" button will not lead to a click on the link, but only expand the code.

Comment: My wild guess: memory corruption. a.k.a. undefined behaviour. Perhaps your stack overlaps your thread structure, so it gets corrupted when the stack gets deeper. Or perhaps serial_printf corrupts it.